# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.0, django-wsgi

I used to check every answer to this question but NOTHING helped me. Here's a full Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/deadpoll/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 44, in get_internal_wsgi_application
return import_string(app_path)
File "/home/deadpoll/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
module = import_module(module_path)
File "/home/deadpoll/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wsgi'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/deadpoll/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/deadpoll/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 140, in inner_run
handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
File "/home/deadpoll/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
File "/home/deadpoll/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 65, in get_handler
return get_internal_wsgi_application()
File "/home/deadpoll/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

Please see my full project on github:

https://github.com/nabirhossain/MyBlog

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure to add your app in the project's `settings.py` file under INSTALLED_APPS.
I was facing the same error, when i had mistakenly added the app under the MIDDLEWARE section.

Answer (score 1):

After a long struggle to get things to work I was able to successfully run the server after making changes from WSGI to asgi  configuration, Its not  a bad thing as asgi is a successor to WSGI
open settings.py delete the WSGI configuration or comment to hide it like the way I did

```
# WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoBlog.wsgi.application' 

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'DjangoBlog.asgi.application'`
```

then create the file named asgi.py and paste this code inside it

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'DjangoBlog.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

DjangoBlog is the name of my project change it to suit yours

Answer (score 0):

Yah the error usually arises when you import something in the middleware setting s that does not exist. the error is not always clear but try going through the imported modules.